# Why are methods after interruption of a thread not called?

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to shutdown a thread gracefully. However, once the shutdown is initiated the thread should perform some shutdown operation after ending usual operation.

Both threads use sleeps and/or wait and handle InterruptedException, they also work on tasks in a loop taking only a few milliseconds. So that I expected the while loop to end because  Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() becomes "true".

The problem is that with my code sometimes I get the log "SHUTDOWN" and sometimes not. Also I get "INTERRUPTED" only sometimes, which I understand of course. With another similar thread I never get the "SHUTDOWN".

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

executor.execute(new Test());

Thread.sleep(10000);

executor.shutdown();
        
try {
    if(this.executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        this.loggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("CLOSED (GRACEFULLY)!");
    }  else {
        this.executor.shutdownNow();
        
        this.loggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("CLOSED (IMMEDIATELY)!");
    }
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    this.executor.shutdownNow();
            
    this.loggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("CLOSED (IMMEDIATELY)!");
}
```

```
class Test implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean isRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                while(!this.isRunning) {
                    synchronized(this) {
                        this.wait();
                    }
                }
                
                // DO SOMETHING LASTING A FEW MILLISECONDS
                    
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            this.loggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("INTERRUPTED!");
        }
        
        this.loggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("SHUTDOWN!");

        // DO SOME SHUTDOWN OPERATION
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want threads to always do some shutdown operations regardless of how they were "told" to stop?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: It seems to me there is likely some exception thrown you’re not seeing. Making the tasks smaller and moving shutdown activities out of them would be good.

Comment: @Martin Who sets that isRunning to false?

Comment: @dreamcrash a stop method. But this is not related to my question and not used. There is actually also a start method which sets it to true.

Comment: Thanks, @NathanHughes this could be true - I will check how we handle this case.

Comment: @Martin This might seems stupid but would it be enough to add finally {
        }  in the run?

Comment: @dreamcrash I already used finally. No difference.

Comment: Maybe some log messages are lost because of shutdown. However, there was the problem with the shutdown operations not run. I now switched to only using the InterruptedException check and use while(true) for the loop. Still need to do some checks.

Comment: @Martin Do you always at least  get one of the two INTERRUPTED or Shutdown ?

Comment: only using the InterruptedException does not help

Comment: @dreamcrash no, sometimes I get them sometimes not. It seems that sometimes also the operations get called and sometimes not. Currently I have to rely on logging and cannot use System.out in order to be sure about the messages.

Comment: @Martin did you with try catch(Exception e)

Comment: @NathanHughes catching all Exceptions does not help. However, this is a good practice and I have implemented it.

Comment: This may help: https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2015/12/06/understanding-thread-interruption-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

After some commentary by OP, an entirely different and much superior solution seems to be available:

### Use hooks!

Java has a system to 'install' a shutdown hook. These are called when the VM shuts down... sometimes. If you get SIGTERMed (`kill -9`) or someone trips over a powercable, or linux kills your process due to excessive memory use, or the kernel dumps, or your VM hard crashes (for example, a core dump in native code), or the device loses power, they don't get called, of course.

But, if someone in the process runs `System.exit()`, or all non-daemon threads are done, or someone hits CTRL+C or sends SIGKILL (`kill`, not `kill -9`) to your process, they get run first, and only when they all finish does the java process actually end.

That sounds like a vastly superior solution here. Your shutdown hook should:

1. acquire the lock on some private AtomicBoolean.
2. set the boolean to false (the boolean indicates: May I query this sensor?)
3. release the lock.
4. reset the sensor.
5. return.

And all your normal operation code that reads that sensor should:

1. acquire a lock on the boolean.
2. if false, throw or otherwise abort.
3. perform the sensor read operation.
4. release the lock.

Nothing should ever touch that sensor without holding the lock (failure to do this would imply maybe messing with that sensor after you've already reset it, which would be bad).

---

original answer:

> I would like to shutdown a thread gracefully.

Why? 'gracefully' is a very nice sounding word, but once you dig into what it means, it's just nasty things. It's a word that means: "That will cause my software to fail, possibly persistently (as in, won't start anymore without cleaning up stuff), if someone trips over a powercable or my app hard-crashes".

A much better design is to have a thread that doesn't *need* to be shut down. Just pull the plug on it, and all is well.

For example, old filesystems (MS-DOS and early windows age) required graceful shutdowns; failure to do so would lead to persistent issues - the system wouldn't boot at all, you bricked the box. They then had mitigation systems in place (chkdsk systems), but modern OSes are much better. Their filesystem handling setup mostly doesn't care about being 'gracefully' shut down. Just pull the plug on em, they'll be fine, that's what journals do.

> `So that I expected the while loop to end because Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() becomes "true".`

That's not how you're supposed to use that API.

Here's the basic gist of what the interrupted API does:

1. Any thread can 'raise the interrupt flag' on any other (`someThread.interrupt()`).
2. raising the flag doesn't do anything other than raise the flag, unless a method explicitly decides to look at it.
3. The method `Thread.interrupted()` is how you're supposed to read the flag out in order to act upon it, __and not `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`. The former will check the flag and clear it. The latter merely checks the flag.
4. Some java methods are specced to respond to the flag being up. You recognize these methods because they `throws InterruptedException`. There may be more methods; for example, on most OSes, interrupting a thread currently waiting for more bytes to flow in from the network (they are blocked on a `read()` call on an `InputStream` obtained from `socket.getInputStream()`) WILL cause that read call to fail (with an IOException, not an InterruptedException, because read() isn't specced to throw InterruptedEx), but that's no guarantee; on some OSes, it won't, and you can't interrupted that.
5. The general policy is that the moment you handle an interrupted flag, you lower the flag, and **java code does just that**: If a method throws InterruptedEx, the flag will be **cleared**.
6. Java does not define what you should do if interrupted. Threads don't get magically interrupted; for example, when your VM shuts down (someone hits CTRL+C), that doesn't interrupt any threads whatsoever. Java will just 'pull the plug' on all threads. That's because this is better (see above). Therefore, if a thread is interrupted, that's because you wrote `thread.interrupt()` someplace, therefore, you decide what it means. Maybe it means 're-read a config file and restart the server listening process'. Maybe it means 'stop calculating chess moves and perform the best move found so far'. Maybe it means 'recheck for a condition'. Maybe it means 'end the thread entirely'. It's up to you. There is no standard.

Note that the various methods specced to respond to interrupt flags (such as `wait()`: It throws InterruptedException) all share this property: If you call them while the flag is up, they will instantly return by throwing `InterruptedException`, they never even begin waiting.

So, for your code, given that you wait() already, just make that `while(true)` and rely on the InterruptedEx.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my system is actually an embedded Linux system and works very well for power-loss cases. We don't have any problem with this case! The reason why we need this is because we have a sensor connected to the system using I2C bus and we need to reset the sensor (because with a software shutdown we DO NOT have power-loss).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your first part is a little weird!

Comment: Why is it weird? Okay, you have a scenario where if your embedded linux system hard-crashes, then you've bricked the device. Can't you reset the sensor on boot? The point is: It's better to not want graceful shutdown, but, hey, sometimes, there's no way out, and perhaps you've got one of these cases. That's why the entire second part of the answer does explain how that interrupt stuff works :P, but, I'm going to edit the answer with a MUCH better suggestion, hold on.

Comment: Regarding 6. We have an OSGi environment and very well handling using shutdown hooks. That's why CTRL+C does allow for shutting down threads.

Comment: No, if the system has power loss it is fine. However, if we restart the application in some cases the I2C bus of connected sensors is in a bad state or should be set to sleep (this is also related to our use of I2C bus communication).

Comment: No we can't reset the sensor on start - too late.